# Is mclapply guaranteed to return its results in order?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore

I'm working with `mclapply` from the `multicore` package (on Ubuntu), and I'm writing a function that required that the results of `mclapply(x, f)` are returned in order (that is, `f(x[1]), f(x[2]), ...., f(x[n])`).

```
# multicore doesn't work on Windows

require(multicore)
unlist(mclapply(
    1:10,
    function(x){
        Sys.sleep(sample(1:5, size = 1))
        identity(x)}, mc.cores = 2))

[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The above code seems to imply that `mclapply` returns results in the same order as `lapply`.

However, if this assumption is wrong I'll have to spend a long time refactoring my code, so I'm hoping to get assurance from someone more familiar with this package/parallel computing that this assumption is correct.

Is it safe to assume that `mclapply` always returns its results in order, regardless of the optional arguments it is given?

Comment: The docs don't indicate that the result may come in scrambled, and it is explicit that this is a parallel version of `lapply`, which returns the list ordered as the input. You could run a portion of your code in sequential and parallel mode and see if this holds for your particular case. I would venture a guess that it does.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Short answer: it does return the results in the correct order.

But of course, you should read the code yourself (`mclapply` is an R function...)

The man page for `collect` gives some more hints:

> Note: If expr uses low-level multicore functions such as sendMaster a single job can deliver results multiple times and it is the responsibility of the user to interpret them correctly.

However, if you don't mess with low-level,

> collect returns any results that are available in a list. **The results will have the same order as the specified jobs.** If there are multiple jobs and a job has a name it will be used to name the result, otherwise its process ID will be used.

(my emphasis)

Now for `mclapply`.
A quick glanc over the source code yields:

- if `!mc.preschedule` and there are no more jobs than cores (`length (X) <= cores`) `parallel` and `collect` are used, see above.
- if `mc.preschedule` or more jobs than cores, `mclapply` itself takes care of the order - see the code.

However, here's a slightly modified version of your experiment:

```
> unlist (mclapply(1:10, function(x){
    Sys.sleep(sample(1:5, size = 1)); 
    cat (x, " ");    
    identity(x)}, 
  mc.cores = 2, mc.preschedule = FALSE))
1  2  4  3  6  5  7  8  9  10   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> unlist (mclapply(1:10, function(x){
    Sys.sleep(sample(1:5, size = 1)); 
    cat (x, " ");    
    identity(x)}, 
  mc.cores = 2, mc.preschedule = TRUE))
1  3  2  5  4  6  7  8  10  9   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Which shows that the results are returned in different order by the child jobs (more precisely: child jobs are about to finish in different order), but the result is assembled in the original order.

(works on the console, but not in RStudio - the `cat`s do not show up there)