# Printing from mclapply in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, mclapply

I am using mclapply from within RStudio and would like to have an output to the console from each process but this seems to be suppressed somehow (as mentioned for example here: [Is mclapply guaranteed to return its results in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697901/is-mclapply-guaranteed-to-return-its-results-in-order/14740525#14740525)).
How could I get R Studio to print something like

`x <- mclapply(1:20, function(i) cat(i, "\n"))`

to the console?

I've tried print(), cat(), write() but they all seem not to work. I also tried to set `mc.silent = FALSE` explicitly without an effect.

Comment: I "solved" the problem by writing the output to a file first and then read and print the content of this file using a small python script. Not nice but enough to get some information about the progress of mclapply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a workaround which uses shell `echo` to print to R console in Rstudio:

```
#' Function which prints a message using shell echo; useful for printing messages from inside mclapply when running in Rstudio
message_parallel <- function(...){
  system(sprintf('echo "\n%s\n"', paste0(..., collapse="")))
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Parallel processing with GUI's is problematic.  I write a lot of parallel code and it's constantly crashing my colleague's computer because he insists on using Rstudio instead of console R.

From what I read, RStudio "does not propagate the output of forked processes to the RStudio console. If you are doing this, it is best to start R via a shell."

This makes sense as a workaround for the RStudio people because parallel processing typically breaks GUI's when people try to output to the GUI from a bunch of different processes.  It works in the console (albeit often not in order) but parallel processing gurus will pinch their noses when they hear about any I/O from a forked thread.

If you must have output from forked threads, save them in a string and return it.  Then collect and output from the main process.  Or just use a console for your parallel runs.  What I tell my colleague is to do all his debugging and development in RStudio using `lapply()`, then switch to a console for the real run.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding a little on the solution used by the asker, i.e. writing to a file to check progress:

```
write.file = '/temp_output/R_progress'

time1 = proc.time()[3]
outstuff = unlist(mclapply(1:1000000, function(i){
  if (i %% 1000 == 0 ){
    file.create(write.file)
    fileConn<-file(write.file)
    writeLines(paste0(i,'/',nrow(loc),' ',(i/nrow(loc)*100)), fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
  }
  #do your stuff here
}, mc.cores=6))
print(proc.time()[3] - time1)
```

And then you can monitor from a console with

> tail -c +0 -f '/temp_output/R_progress'