# Using mclapply in a function in custom R package

Tags: r, r-package, rparallel

I used R Studio to create a package using these two sites as guides:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio
https://www.r-bloggers.com/building-a-package-in-rstudio-is-actually-very-easy/

The only modification is when I created the package using R Studio I used the option to create an R package with Rcpp.

One of the functions in the package is the following:

```
GenerateSims = function(num.sim, alpha0, alpha1, beta1, gamma1, delta, n.sim, covariates, burnin, type)
{
  print("In GenerateSims")

  sims = mclapply(1:num.sim, function(z) {
    GenerateData(alpha0, alpha1, beta1, gamma1, delta, n.sim, covariates, burnin, type)
  },
  mc.cores = 35)

  print("Leaving GenerateSims...")
  return(sims)
}
```

When `mc.cores =  1` it runs fine. When I set mc.cores to something other than 1 the console prints out "In GenerateSims" but stops there as if it's in an infinite loop.

The function GenerateData only uses one function from a non base package `gamlss.dist::rDPO`.

My DESCRIPTION file is as follows (not sure if this helps identify the issue or not):

```
Package: Summer2017Package
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports: Rcpp (>= 0.12.9), gamlss.dist, parallel, moments, stats
LinkingTo: Rcpp
```

EDIT: I am running this on a machine running Debian.

Comment: Are you on a windows machine? If so - per the documentations: It relies on forking and hence is **not available on Windows** unless mc.cores = 1.

Comment: It's running on a debian machine.

Comment: You should remove the edit from your question and repost it as an answer, then accept it. This way if anyone else has this problem in the future they can more easily find a possible solution

Comment: Will do HFBrowning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that within the GenerateData function there was a print statement. I got rid of this and it fixed my issue. I also came across this post, [Printing from mclapply in R Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345837/printing-from-mclapply-in-r-studio), that mentioned this isn't an issue when running an R script from the command line. So that's an easier fix than getting rid of my print statements.